# Why the predictions are very off (which causes very large losses)?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, prediction, loss-function

I have this very simple resnet18 network that I am trying to train from scratch for task of landmark estimation (I have 4 landmarks):

```
num_classes = 4 * 2 #4 coordinates X and Y flattened --> 4 of 2D keypoints or landmarks

class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,num_classes=8):
        super().__init__()
        self.model_name = 'resnet18'
        self.model = models.resnet18()
        self.model.fc = nn.Linear(self.model.fc.in_features, num_classes)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.float()
        out = self.model(x)
        return out
```

For the following piece of code:

```
network = Network()
network.cuda()    

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(network.parameters(), lr=0.0001)

loss_min = np.inf
num_epochs = 1

start_time = time.time()
for epoch in range(1,num_epochs+1):
    
    loss_train = 0
    loss_test = 0
    running_loss = 0
    
    
    network.train()
    print('size of train loader is: ', len(train_loader))

    for step in range(1,len(train_loader)+1):

        
        batch = next(iter(train_loader))
        images, landmarks = batch['image'], batch['landmarks']
        #RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 7, 7], expected input[64, 600, 800, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 600 channels instead
        #using permute to fix the above error
        images = images.permute(0,3,1,2)
        
        images = images.cuda()
    
        landmarks = landmarks.view(landmarks.size(0),-1).cuda() 
        
        
        ##images = torchvision.transforms.Normalize(images) #find the args later
        ##landmarks = torchvision.transforms.Normalize(landmarks) #find the args later
        
        predictions = network(images)
        
        # clear all the gradients before calculating them
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        print('predictions are: ', predictions.float())
        print('landmarks are: ', landmarks.float())
        # find the loss for the current step
        loss_train_step = criterion(predictions.float(), landmarks.float())
        
        
        loss_train_step = loss_train_step.to(torch.float32)
        print("loss_train_step before backward: ", loss_train_step)
        
        # calculate the gradients
        loss_train_step.backward()
        
        # update the parameters
        optimizer.step()
        
        print("loss_train_step after backward: ", loss_train_step)

        
        loss_train += loss_train_step.item()
        
        print("loss_train: ", loss_train)
        running_loss = loss_train/step
        print('step: ', step)
        print('running loss: ', running_loss)
        
        print_overwrite(step, len(train_loader), running_loss, 'train')
        
    network.eval() 
    with torch.no_grad():
        
        for step in range(1,len(test_loader)+1):
            
            batch = next(iter(train_loader))
            images, landmarks = batch['image'], batch['landmarks']
            images = images.permute(0,3,1,2)
            images = images.cuda()
            landmarks = landmarks.view(landmarks.size(0),-1).cuda()
        
            predictions = network(images)

            # find the loss for the current step
            loss_test_step = criterion(predictions, landmarks)

            loss_test += loss_test_step.item()
            running_loss = loss_test/step

            print_overwrite(step, len(test_loader), running_loss, 'Validation')
    
    loss_train /= len(train_loader)
    loss_test /= len(test_loader)
    
    print('\n--------------------------------------------------')
    print('Epoch: {}  Train Loss: {:.4f} Valid Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch, loss_train, loss_test))
    print('--------------------------------------------------')
    
    if loss_test < loss_min:
        loss_min = loss_test
        torch.save(network.state_dict(), '../moth_landmarks.pth') 
        print("\nMinimum Valid Loss of {:.4f} at epoch {}/{}".format(loss_min, epoch, num_epochs))
        print('Model Saved\n')
     
print('Training Complete')
print("Total Elapsed Time : {} s".format(time.time()-start_time))
```

I get this NAN as well as very large MSE losses (showing only for one step):

```
size of train loader is:  90
predictions are:  tensor([[-0.0380, -0.1871,  0.0729, -0.3570, -0.2153,  0.3066,  1.1273, -0.0558],
        [-0.0316, -0.1876,  0.0317, -0.3613, -0.2333,  0.3023,  1.0940, -0.0665],
        [-0.0700, -0.1882,  0.0068, -0.3201, -0.1884,  0.2953,  1.0516, -0.0567],
        [-0.0844, -0.2009,  0.0573, -0.3166, -0.2597,  0.3127,  1.0343, -0.0573],
        [-0.0486, -0.2333,  0.0535, -0.3245, -0.2310,  0.2818,  1.0590, -0.0716],
        [-0.0240, -0.1989,  0.0572, -0.3135, -0.2435,  0.2912,  1.0612, -0.0560],
        [-0.0942, -0.2439,  0.0277, -0.3147, -0.2368,  0.2978,  1.0110, -0.0874],
        [-0.0356, -0.2285,  0.0064, -0.3179, -0.2432,  0.3083,  1.0300, -0.0756]],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
landmarks are:  tensor([[501.9200, 240.1600, 691.0000, 358.0000, 295.0000, 294.0000, 488.6482,
         279.6466],
        [495.6300, 246.0600, 692.0000, 235.0000, 286.0000, 242.0000, 464.0000,
         339.0000],
        [488.7100, 240.8900, 613.4007, 218.3425, 281.0000, 220.0000, 415.9966,
         338.4796],
        [502.5721, 245.4983, 640.0000, 131.0000, 360.0000, 143.0000, 542.9840,
         321.8463],
        [505.1393, 246.4364, 700.0000, 306.0000, 303.0000, 294.0000, 569.6925,
         351.8367],
        [501.0900, 244.0100, 724.0000, 251.0000, 302.0000, 276.0000, 504.6415,
         291.7443],
        [495.9500, 244.2800, 608.0000, 127.0000, 323.0000, 166.0000, 491.0000,
         333.0000],
        [490.2500, 241.3400, 699.0000, 304.0000, 398.6197, 313.8339, 429.1374,
         303.8483]], device='cuda:0')
loss_train_step before backward:  tensor(166475.6875, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)
loss_train_step after backward:  tensor(166475.6875, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)
loss_train:  166475.6875
step:  1
running loss:  166475.6875
```

The other thing besides Network I am also suspicious of is the transforms:

Here's the transforms I am using:

```
transformed_dataset = MothLandmarksDataset(csv_file='moth_gt.csv',
                                           root_dir='.',
                                           transform=transforms.Compose(
                                               [
                                               Rescale(256),
                                               RandomCrop(224),
                                               
                                               ToTensor()#,
                                               ##transforms.Normalize(mean = [ 0.485, 0.456, 0.406 ],
                                               ##         std = [ 0.229, 0.224, 0.225 ])
                                               ]
                                                                        )
                                           )
```

How can I fix it? Also, with having Normalize I do still get same problem (NAN and very large loss values since the predictions are very off).

How can I basically debug why the predictions are very off?

Comment: I see you're only using 1 epoch, have you tried more?

Comment: well, it's even worse. I am showing one epochs just for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the way you are using `DataLoader`. `iter(train_loader)` creates an iterator out of the data loader and calling `next` should give you the next example from dataset. But you are calling `next(iter(train_loader))` in each iteration which creates a new iterator each time from `train_loader` and returns the next example which would essentially be the first example in your dataset. So i think this way you end up training (and validating) on the same example in each iteration. Even if your data loader shuffles the dataset each time, you'll end up training on some random samples from the dataset (as each time only the first random sample will be used) and not on the complete dataset. Try changing your code such that you use `iter(train_loader)` only once and and call `next` in each iteration:

```
train_iter = iter(train_loader)
for step in range(1, len(train_loader)+1):
    batch = next(train_iter)
    # now batch contains (step)th batch (assuming 1-based indexing)
```

Or even better change your `for` loop to iterate on the `train_loader` itself:

```
for step, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
    # now batch contains (step)th batch (assuming 0-based indexing)
```

Similar change would also be required for validation or evaluation. Let me know if this resolves your problem or helps in any way.